# osxfuse: how to clean cache?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osxfuse

How to clean cache in OSXFUSE? I'm using it to mount custom remote filesystem. And OSXFUSE caching file content. It is great to fast access for the same file - but sometimes I need to re-read file content from remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, that you can clean this cache. But you can disable UBC (Unified Buffer Cache) by specifying 'noubc' in mount options (see [OSXFUSE mount options](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options#noubc))
It will disable caching your responses to 'read' calls and osxfuse will perform calls into your filesystem without using cache.